# How can I represent Delphi style enumerated types in XSD?

Tags: xml, delphi, xsd, enumeration

In a Delphi application, I declared this enumeration:

```
TReportEnum=(Report1,Report2,Report3,Report4,Report5);
```

Correspondingly, I set up an XSD enumeration like this:

```
<xs:simpleType name="Reports">
    <xs:restriction base="xs:token">
        <xs:enumeration value="Report1"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="Report2"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="Report3"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="Report4"/>
        <xs:enumeration value="Report5"/>
    </xs:restriction>
</xs:simpleType>
```

The enumeration values in this XSD are tokens/strings that correspond to the enumerated type values in Delphi (or C++), which are essentially just named constants for integers. So, when I process XML based on this XSD in my application, I am forced to cast the XML strings of the enumeration to TReportEnum(strtoInt(XMLEnum)) before I can process, which reduces the usefullness of the XSD enumeration.

In [Skonnard and Gudgin](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0201740958) I looked through all the data types available for declaring enumerations and I couldn't find anything that would allow me to emulate in XSD/XML a numeric value as a named constant, along the lines of a named constant or enum in Delphi/C++.

Am I missing something? Am I trying to do the impossible? If not, how do I do this?

Comment: Do you want to create a Delphi enum type on the fly based on a XSD that you read in, or do you want to create the enum-type in XSD used a predefined Delphi type?

Comment: You'd need to have a reference to `TReportEnum` in there as well, or how will Delphi know the type of your enum?